# Integrating our Development evironment Pega 7 with VersionOne

Tags: pega

we are trying to integrate our day to day code changes to a specific user story with Version One So that we can keep track of user story and rules modified.

Please clarify below points in order to proceed further.

1. Is it possible to update Version One User story with some data?
2. If it is possible , what are the parameters that are mandatory to send to Version One data base.
3. what is the authentication methods that is used to access version one through a web service.
4. From our side, to integrate our development environment(PEGA 7) with version one through a connect-soap, we need below data.

   - Operation Name
   - WSDL URL
   - Sample request and response.
5. if this is not possible , what are the other ways we can integrate our development environment with Version One.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards,
Raju G
+91 7799234226

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to update Version One User story with some data?

Yes it is possible to update a Story.  You can use either a raw API or SDK which is a wrapper around the VersionOne Rest API.

> If it is possible , what are the parameters that are mandatory to send to Version One data base. In order to update a Story, one can assume that when the story was created, all of the mandatory parameters were filled in.  There is an exception though.  If a VersionOne admin added a mandatory attribute on "Stories" after a particular Story was created and this mandatory field was not populated when this particular Story was created, when you attempt to update this Story, you will get an exception unless you also update this mandatory field.  I suggest that you go to the http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library and start playing with the API.
>
> what is the authentication methods that is used to access version one through a web service.

The VersionOne API is accessible via Basic, Oauth & Access Token authentication methods.

> From our side, to integrate our development environment(PEGA 7) with version one through a connect-soap, we need below data.
>           Operation Name
>           WSDL URL
>           Sample request and response.
>   if this is not possible , what are the other ways we can integrate our development environment with Version One.

VersionOne is not a SOAP web service but is a Rest service.   Once again, take a look at the VersionOne API or SDK docs and get a feel for what you can do then you can decide how you want to integrate with your existing app.